# What is the gdbus library name? Technique to find it?

Tags: c, linux, glib

What library do I need to include to use Bluez `gdbus.h` functions? I am getting alot of `undefined reference` errors for `gdbus.h` functions so I obviously I am missing a library.

*Is there a way (in terminal or otherwise) I can find out what library a header file uses? For example; I can find where a header file resides using `locate gdbus.h`. Is there a way I can find out what library `gdbus.h` requires?

My current `pkg-config` is:

> pkg-config --cflags gio-2.0 dbus-glib-1 dbus-1 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0
>   pkg-config --libs gio-2.0 dbus-glib-1 dbus-1 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0

With this I get many undefined references such as:

> agent.c:100: undefined reference to 'g_dbus_send_reply'
>   agent.c:104: undefined reference to 'g_dbus_send_reply'
>   agent.c:107: undefined reference to 'g_dbus_send_error'

What library am I missing?

Comment: What is the output of those `pkg-config` commands with `gio-2.0` by itself?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune if I just use `gio-2.0` by itself I get the compile error `fatal error: gdbus/gdbus.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: How did you install BlueZ? GDBus isn't from DBus, it's a file written by BlueZ developers IIRC to provide helper/wrapper functions. In the header you can clearly see that it depends on glib.h and dbus/dbus.h. glib is from GIO iirc. Gdbus.h is in the source of BlueZ. Not anywhere in a package.

Comment: This is what you're looking for, by the way.
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/gdbus

Answer (score 9):

The gdbus functions are part of the gio library, so the `gio-2.0` package is what you want.

The reason `gdbus/gdbus.h` isn't found is that it doesn't exist.  I don't even have a package which provides a `gdbus.h`, much less `gdbus/gdbus.h`.  The right file to include is `gio/gio.h`, which will include all the necessary headers for the entire gio library, including the 22 for gdbus.

Get rid of `dbus-glib-1`; it's deprecated (in favor of gdbus).  If your code uses gdbus it's very unlikely it also requires dbus-glib.

Comment: gdbus/gdbus.h is found in the BlueZ source code, not in a package. It does exist.

Answer (score 2):

`gbdus.h` is located in the BlueZ user space source code, which in order to use, should be [downloaded](http://www.bluez.org/download/) and maybe compiled.

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/gdbus

The link above points to the folder that you're looking for in the source of this user space package. The header file is in there too. The file structure corresponds to the structure of the user space source code you should have downloaded. From there you can include the files you were missing.